# How to open page in a new popup window?

Tags: visualforce

In page:

```
 <apex:commandLink value="Action Planner" action="{!started}"  styleClass="start" target="_blank"/>
```

In Class:

```
  public PageReference started(){ return new PageReference('/apex/ActionListed');}
```

How can I open this in a new popup window??target=_blank just opens it in a new tab not in  new window.

Comment: Refer this link with lots of information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939928/make-a-link-open-a-new-window-not-tab

Comment: There shouldn't be any PageReferences in this request.  That is only for navigating pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Haven't tried it in my org. You may need to change the width & height.

[image]

Comment: Yes its working but I am not able to maximize it?why so?

Comment: Its working fine now